# C++ Template Function specialization error

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I am new in using C++ templates.
I need to write a template function specialization for my project. 
It is a simple Sum function for different type inputs and it calculates the sum between two iterators. The original function is generic and so accepts a template argument. The template specialization is written for Maps.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
double Sum(T &it_beg, T &it_end) {
    double sum_all = 0;

    for(it_beg++; it_beg != it_end; it_beg++)
        sum_all += *it_beg;

    return sum_all;
};

template <>
double Sum(std::map<std::string, double> &it_beg, std::map<std::string, double> &it_end) {
    double sum_all = 0;

    for(it_beg++; it_beg != it_end; it_beg++)
        sum_all += it_beg->second;

    return sum_all;
};
```

when I try to run the code, I get the following errors

```
...\sum.h(21): error C2676: binary '++' : 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' does not define     this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              _Kty=std::string,
 1>              _Ty=double
 1>          ]
```

I appreciate if anyone could give me a hint ! 
thanks

Comment: Something is wrong with your for-loops.

Comment: post fix increment operator is not defined for std::map<std::string, double>  your parameter type should be std::map<std::string, double>::iterator for the increment to work.

Comment: Yeah. I just noticed that. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function signature should look like this (possibly without references) so you can pass in rvalues (iterators are cheap to copy anyway):

```
template <>
double Sum(std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it_beg,
           std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it_end)
```

`std::map` does not define `operator++`, clearly your arguments are meant to be `std::map::iterator`s.

Don't forget to remove the references from the main template function parameters too.

There's also this:

```
for(it_beg++; it_beg != it_end; it_beg++)
```

Why are you incrementing `it_beg` as you enter the loop? You can leave initialization statement empty.

Comment: Thanks ! That really helps. Just one more question, when I try to separate the implementation by creating cpp file, I get a linker error !! It works perfectly when I include everything in hpp but as soon as I create cpp I get the link error ( obviously in this case I include cpp file in the main program). You have any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: [Templates can be implemented only in header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: I read that post and followed their guides but still I have problem separating the header from implementation. I created another post since it may be of interest for other people. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292476/c-template-specialization-linker-error   Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Hamed You shouldn't separate them. That's what I tried to tell you.